# Using reCaptcha in qutebrowser

Tags: browser, captcha

I'm trying to pass one of the "I'm not a robot" captchas, using an unmodified qutebrowser. I'm on version 1.5.2, and when I click the box it just loops and doesn't terminate.

I've tried clicking the box with and without hints, and neither seems to work. Is this a common problem, and can I resolve it?